# Merging list of uneven length with default value for missing matches

Tags: scala

Im trying to pair up two lists in Scala where non matching pairs should be replaced by a default value, this is what I have so far but thy all fall short in some way.

> How do I create List((a,a),(b,empty),(c,c))???

```
case class Test(id: Option[Int] = None)
val empty = Test()
val a = Test(Some(1))
val b = Test(Some(2))
val c = Test(Some(3))

val cache = List(a,b,c)
val delta = List(a,c)

//Trial 1
val newCache1 = cache.zipAll(delta,empty,empty)

//Tial 2
val newCache2 = for {
  c <- cache
  d <- delta
  if c.id == d.id
} yield (c,d)

//Tial 3
val newCache3 = for {
  c <- cache
  d <- delta
} yield if (c.id == d.id) (c,d) else (c,empty)
```

Comment: Can there be duplicates ? Are the lists ordered ?  You could put delta in a map, then pick the pair out of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your delta into a map, then join them up.

```
  val deltaMap: Map[Int, Test] =
    delta.flatMap(x => x.id.map(id => id -> x)).toMap

  val newCache: Seq[(Test, Test)] = cache.map { c =>
    c -> c.id.flatMap(deltaMap.get).getOrElse(empty)
  }
```